# WebClient received more bytes than TotalBytesToReceive

Tags: c#, .net, download, webclient

I am running a Task on a list of remote files.
On every file I am `using` a `WebClient` and performing `webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...)`.

In the `WebClient`'s DownloadProgressChanged handler I notice that the summing up `e.BytesReceived` until the completion of the task, gives a much higher result than the size I get by `e.TotalBytesToReceive`.

Sometimes the sum of the received bytes is exactly double of the size of the file, sometimes is much higher.

The size I get with `e.TotalBytesToReceive` is correct, is the same size i get with `ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]` and checking the real file I am sure that the size is correct.

Why am I getting these values? Is there a header, or something, I have to remove in order to get the correct progress of the download?

---

The methods that download the files are

```
private async Task DownloadFiles(List<FileDetails> files)
{            
    await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(p => DownloadFileAsync(p)));
}
```

and

```
private async Task DownloadFileAsync(FileDetails f)
{
    string localPath = @"C:\myDir";
    try
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += MyHandler;
            webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(f.Path, localPath);
        }
    }
    catch ()
    {
    }
}
```

And the code that handles the progress:

```
void MyHandler(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //GlobalProgress and GlobalPercentage are global variables 
    //initialized at zero before the download task starts.
    GlobalProgress += e.BytesReceived;
    //UpdateDownloadTotal is the sum of the sizes of the 
    //files I have to download
    GlobalPercentage = GlobalProgress * 100 / UpdateDownloadTotal;
}
```

Comment: _Is there a header, or something, I have to remove in order to get the correct progress of the download?_ - the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs.bytesreceived?view=netframework-4.7.2) suggest _"To determine what percentage of the transfer has occurred, use the ProgressPercentage property."_

Comment: ProgressPercentage property gives me the progress percentage of each Handler call. Summing up the percentage I receive I get a total of 130% ÷ 170%...

Comment: Oh right, well that's not ideal. Can you show the code that reports the download progress?

Comment: @stuartd edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the example given for the [`BytesReceived` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.downloadprogresschangedeventargs.bytesreceived?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples):

> ```
> private static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
> {
>     // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
>     Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...", 
>         (string)e.UserState, 
>         e.BytesReceived, 
>         e.TotalBytesToReceive,
>         e.ProgressPercentage);
> }
> ```

Note that it's reporting the value simply as "transfer progress". I agree that the documentation could be more thorough here because it is slightly ambiguous, but for me (with this example<sup>1</sup>), it's clear that `BytesReceived` is "how many bytes have been received since we started this download", not "how many bytes have been received since this event was last raised".

As such, there's no need for *you* to accumulate the count - the accumulated count is what's already being given to you. And that's why you're getting overcounts - if its downloading 100k raises the event twice, once at the 50k mark and once at the 100k, as an example, your `GlobalProgress` will be 150k.

Agree with other comments though that you should just use `ProgressPercentage` to get the percentage.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since a message stating `downloaded x of y bytes` is practically useless if `y` is the expected total but `x` is just the delta since the message was last displayed.

Comment: Problem is, that I have multiple async tasks running simultaneously but I only want to show the overall progress. Anyway, thanks to your suggestion, I understood the problem and solved the mystery: now I calculate the delta by myself to get the overall progress percentage.